# Why is my FirestoreRecyclerView not automatically showing the latest items after I login to my application?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have a problem with my FirestoreRecyclerView where it will not automatically show the latest items added when I login to the application. I have to manually scroll up the recyclerview, then the newly added items will be shown.

Brief description of my app: My application will record a log every minute.FirestoreRecyclerView should show the latest logs at the top of the recyclerview every minute.

My problem is, when I logged in at 3.53pm, the previous logs which I logged in at 3.16pm are shown instead.

[image]

However, if I scroll up, I will see the latest 3.53pm log:

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening. Is there a way to show the latest log without having to scroll up? Or is there a way to clear the FirestoreRecyclerView everytime I log in?

Logs Fragment Class:

```
public class UserLogsFragment extends Fragment implements UserLogsAdapter.OnListItemClick{

private RecyclerView mFirestoreList;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
private UserLogsAdapter adapter;
private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserLogsModel> options;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_logs2, container, false);


    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    // Query from firebase
    Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("UOW_log") // TODO: filter by organisation ID
            .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);


    // Recycler options
    options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserLogsModel>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<UserLogsModel>() {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public UserLogsModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                    UserLogsModel userLogsModel = snapshot.toObject(UserLogsModel.class);
                    String docId = snapshot.getId();
                    userLogsModel.setDocument_id(docId);
                    return userLogsModel;
                }
            })
            .build();

    // Create recycler adapter
    adapter = new UserLogsAdapter(options, this);
    mFirestoreList = view.findViewById(R.id.firestore_list2);
    mFirestoreList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFirestoreList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    mFirestoreList.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(UserLogsModel snapshot, int position) {
    Log.d("ITEM_CLICK", "Clicked the item: " + position + " and the ID is: " + snapshot.getDocument_id());
    //startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LogsDetailActivity.class));



    Fragment fragment = UserLogDetailsFragment.newInstance(snapshot.getDocument_id());
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();



    //transaction.hide(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("user_logs_fragment"));
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "user_log_details_fragment");
    //transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();



    /*
    transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);//add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
    */



}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class UserLogsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<UserLogsModel, UserLogsAdapter.UserLogsViewHolder> {

private OnListItemClick onListItemClick;

public UserLogsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserLogsModel> options, OnListItemClick onListItemClick) {
    super(options);

    this.onListItemClick = onListItemClick;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserLogsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserLogsModel model) {

    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
        // Do your binding here
        holder.doc_id.setText(model.getDocument_id());

    }

    //holder.doc_id.setText(model.getDocument_id());
    Log.d("POSITION","Position: " + position);





}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserLogsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_logs_list_item_single2, parent, false);
    return new UserLogsViewHolder(view);
}

// Viewholder class for user logs
protected class UserLogsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView doc_id;

    public UserLogsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        doc_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userLogs_recyView_docId2);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onListItemClick.onItemClick(getItem(getAdapterPosition()), getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public interface OnListItemClick{
    void onItemClick(UserLogsModel snapshot, int position);
}


}
```

Comment: What is the code that produces this behavior?

Comment: @AlexMamo hi i have edited my codes!